# Splitting txt file to new lines

Tags: php, file, split

I have a big txt file goes like this:
"Hello how are you878SAZIm Fine Thank you878SAZHave a Nice Day"

I want to split this file to new line every time i see "878SAZ" and save it as txt.. ive tried couple of things but im unable to do this, what to do?

```
$txt_file = file_get_contents('C:/files/file.txt');
$rows = explode("878SAZ", $txt_file);

array_shift($rows);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
}
file_put_contents("C:/files/file.txt, $rows)";
```

Comment: You are expected to show your effort. Show what you have tried, even if it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing the string '878SAZ' with "\n" which means newline

```
$input = file_get_contents(YOUR_FILE_PATH);
$text = str_replace('878SAZ', "\n", $input);
file_put_contents(WRITE_FILE_PATH, $text);
```